# App crashes when resuming setActionBarTitle issue

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar, resume

My app crashes whenever I resume it if it has been in the background for say 15 - 20 minutes. The culprit is this line `((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Stories");` which is in my Viewfragment.

The line references this on my MainActivity

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
```

Here's how  the app looks ..

MainActivity->>ViewFragment->> Fragment1 OR Fragment2.

Whenever I resume the app from Another Activity inside Fragment1 , then press back to go to Fragment1 and then back again to ViewFragment it crashes pointing to the above line..Log is as below:

My best guess is that MainActivity was long killed thus unable to start...How can i solve this?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.reelforge.utility/com.reelforge.utility.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.reelforge.utility.MainActivity.setActionBarTitle(MainActivity.java:155)
 at com.reelforge.utility.Viewfragment.ViewFragment.onCreate(ViewFragment.java:32)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1939)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2037)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:154)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:289)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
 at br.liveo.navigationliveo.NavigationLiveo.onCreate(NavigationLiveo.java:112)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interface to set Title of MainActivity eg.

```
public interface ToolbarListener {
    void setTitle(String title);
}
```

implement this in your MainActiviy like this

```
@Override
public void setTitle(String title) {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

and finally call it in OnAttach() of your fragments like this

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof ToolbarListener) {
        ((ToolbarListener) context).setTitle("My Title");
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working.. What does this line mean?  if (context instanceof ToolbarListener)

Comment: if (context instanceof ToolbarListener) it check whether context is instance of Interface which we have created.

Comment: Thanks...Worked great

Answer (score 0):

You should use an interface to interact between fragments and activities(http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). Also a precaution, just before `((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Stories");` you should check rewrite is as-

```
if(isVisible()) {
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Stories");
}
```

in the on resume of your fragment.